# Getting a value from an array and searching for it in a string PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a values from the following array:

```
$array = ["jack", "name", "father"];
```

Then i want to get back the line of where the word appears in in the following string:

```
$story = "Hello, my name is jack and i'm in the army. I've been in the army for 10 years. My father was also in the army.";
```

The outcome should be:

```
"Hello, my name is jack and i'm in the army. My father was also in the army.";
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: By `line` u mean `sentence`?

Comment: yes by line i mean each sentence.

Answer (score 1):

### This is custom way to get desire Output string

```
<?php
$array = ["jack", "name", "father"];
$story = "Hello, my name is jack and i'm in the army. I've been in the army for 10 years. My father was also in the army.";
$return = [];
$splitStory = explode(".", $story);
$data = array_filter($splitStory);
//echo "<pre>";
//print_r(array_filter($splitStory));
$count = count($data);
$count2 = count($data);
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    for($j=0; $j < $count2; $j++)
    {
        if (strpos($data[$i], $array[$j]) !== false) {
            $return[] = $data[$i];
        } 
    }
}
$returnArray = array_unique($return);
$returnStr = implode(".", $returnArray);
echo $returnStr;  // Output : Hello, my name is jack and i'm in the army. My father was also in the army
?>
```

1. **[array_unique()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_unique.asp) Function** :- The array_unique() function removes duplicate values from an array. If two or more array values
   are the same, the first appearance will be kept and the other will
   be removed.
2. **[array_filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_filter.asp) Function** :- The array_filter() function filters the values of an array using a callback function.
3. **[explode()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp) Function** :- The explode() function breaks a string into an array.
4. **[implode()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp) Function** :- The implode() function returns a string from the elements of an array.